# Installed certificate but iOS safari keeps showing "cannot verify the identity of the website"

Tags: ios, ssl, ssh, https

I have a server running with a certificate generated with:

Update: Also tried this: https://blog.httpwatch.com/2013/12/12/five-tips-for-using-self-signed-ssl-certificates-with-ios/

1. openssl genrsa -out myselfsigned.key 2048
2. openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -key myselfsigned.key -out myselfsigned.cer -days 365
   -subj /CN=x.x.x.x
3. Imported the certificate to mac keychain - works fine.
4. **Update 1**: Emailed the certificate(or see [this](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2013/12/12/five-tips-for-using-self-signed-ssl-certificates-with-ios/)) to my iPhone and installed it with a green checkmark. That is, it is installed alright saying Verified.
    
   **this did not work.** as 
   when I open the site in iOS Safari keeps popping up with a message "cannot verify the identity of the website"

Do you know what I am missing?

**Update 2**: I tried the answer from Marcus Adams, same result.

**Update 3**: I also tried to import and then export the certificate from KeyChain. The idea was that in KeyChain you can set the Trus to "Always trust", if this should be the missing part - **but no?**
Regards

Comment: You need to be more specific as to what part of step 4 above did not work.  Does it install but say "not trusted" does it nor let you install? Are you using the standard Mail app to try to open the cert?  What type of file do you export the cert as?

Comment: Thanks, see update. I did not export anything? Just emailed the cert generated with openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -key myselfsigned.key -out myselfsigned.cer -days 365 -subj /CN=x.x.x.x

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the Certificate Authority step.

You need to:

1. Create a CA certificate
2. Create a CSR
3. Self-sign your CSR with the CA cert
4. **Install the CA certificate on the device**

Here's a link to an article with instructions for creating a CA certificate and self-signing with that:

[Be your own Certificate Authority (CA)](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2005/11/10/be-your-own-ca/)

Comment: Thanks. I have followed this step by step. Installed myca.crt & server.crt & server-key-cert.pem on the device. And still iOS Safari pops up saying it can not verify the identity. Again it works on mac Safari after importing the server.crt into keychain. Hmm